# Why Cheese Box may contain nuts?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-curse-of-the-were-rabbit

In [Wallace & Gromit: The Curse of the Were-Rabbit (2005)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0312004), Gromit gave this cheese box to Wallace to cover his private part before Her Ladyship.

[image]

But this Cheese Box is labelled "May Contain Nuts"

Why would a Cheese Box be labelled as **"May Contain Nuts"**?

Comment: Why *wouldn’t* a cheese box contain nuts? https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/x/cheese-nuts-28248589.jpg

Answer (score 47, accepted):

**It's a joke (for the most part)**

Firstly, the "May Contain" is a common warning in many countries by manufacturers to indicate that not only might the product *actually* contain allergen items but **also** that the allergen may have entered the product *accidentally* ... usually as it was manufactured in the same plant where the allergen was being used.

> Manufacturers often use phrases such as 'may contain' to show that there could be small amounts of an allergen for example milk, egg, nuts etc. in a food product because it has entered the product accidentally during the production process.
>
> It's not a legal requirement to say on the label that a food might accidentally contain small amounts of an allergen, but many manufacturers label their products in this way to warn their customers of this risk.
>
> <sup>[**Food.gov.uk**](https://www.food.gov.uk/science/allergy-intolerance/label)</sup>

---

But secondly, **and perhaps more importantly**, nuts is used as a *double entendre* to imply testicles since Wallace is naked in the box....or perhaps that Wallace is just a little crazy (nuts).

Comment: Technically, he's "naked in the box" the same way I'm "naked underneath my clothes."

Comment: @fluffy I disagree. "Naked" is usually taken to mean "not wearing any clothes", and a box doesn't usually count as clothing.

Comment: @fluffy [Everyone's naked underneath.](https://youtu.be/Ei2quMm4qHk?t=65)

Comment: @randal'thor Not sure I want to open a youtube link with that description...

Comment: @Kevin It's just a naked alien, no worries.

Comment: Not that it really matters when it's a joke, but as well as the "processed in the same plant as nuts, may contain traces", some cheeses do actually have nuts in, e.g. walnuts in 
http://www.thecheeseandwineshop.co.uk/products/rambol-walnut-cheese-125g-individual.asp http://www.thecheeseandwineshop.co.uk/products/saint-julien-cheese-150g-individual.asp

Answer (score -3):

If the law requires potential allergens to be declared, then listing as many possible allergens as they can on *each* product covers them -- they won't be sued if one piece of nut ends up in the box and someone chokes on it.

This, of course, defeats the purpose of the law -- by "crying wolf", no one knows anymore which products contain what allergens.  I believe these laws will be strengthened in the future; after people get used to the current system.

Comment: I don't want to be rude, but this completely misses the point of the label in this movie.

Comment: Hmmm -- I took the question literally.  I saw the movie still, but thought that was a just side comment.